# Selecting A Dynamic range in Excel using Python - Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with data in column A. I want to loop through each cell and select the row that that i first come across that has a formula.

This is my code:

```
import openpyxl 
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(path1)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

names=sheet['A']

for cellObj in names:
    val = str(cellObj.value)
    if val[0] == "=":
        #select the row from column A to Z and make it's values equal to itself (like doing a copy/pasteSpecial values in excel to remove the formula)
```

I guess i can append the row in an empty list then make it equal to the row again, but how do i even do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You check for the `cell.data_type == "f"`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just wanted to remove the formula and leave the actual data itself? If you want this for the whole file then add data_only=True. I also suggest saving the workbook in a different filename or create a copy of original excel file.

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path1, data_only=True) 
wb.save(save_path)
wb.close()
```

Comment: I am only trying to remove the formula from the FIRST row that contains a formula. I have many other formulas elsewhere i don't want to remove.